# How do i get only the first links without using id or class in the dropdown menu but not in the submenu. The Tags in HTML are quite nested and similar

Tags: css, css-selectors

i'm trying very hard to get the first link, see below. They are very hard to get without class or id. I tried all, nothing works because the selector are nested und similar.

```html
     <nav>
            <ul>
                <li>
                    <a href="#">First</a> /* this one */
                    <ul>
                        <li>
                            <a href="#">First menu item</a>
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            <a href="#">Second menu item</a>
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            <a href="#">Another one</a>
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            <a href="#">Last one</a>
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a href="#">Second menu item</a>  /* this one */
                    <ul class="m1">
                        <li>
                            <a href="#">Another menu item</a>
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            <a href="#">Next one</a>
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            <a href="#">Last one</a>
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
              </ul>
            </na>
```

Answer (score 1):

if you have only one nav and one menu, you can use this one:

```css
nav > ul > li > a { /* styles */ }
```

Comment: Thx a lot, it works. Have a nice day :)

Comment: Sorry, it only selects the first menu point, but not the second. Thx for trying!

Comment: here we go: nav > ul > li > a. Thx for the Aha-effect!!!!!

Answer (score -2):

Assuming the `nav` element is unique on the page, you can simply select the link based on that it is within the first LI in the top-level UL:

```
nav > ul > li:first-child > a { color: red; }
```

Comment: nice work!!!!! thx a million!!!!!!!!

Comment: Sorry, it only selects the first menu point, but not the second. Thx for trying!

Comment: here we go: nav > ul > li > a. Thx for the Aha-effect!!!!!